# Specify HTML DOM nodes for Google page translation (opposite of class=notranslate)

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I know you can tell google translate not to translate some sections by using `class="notranslate"`, but can you tell google to translate only specific sections and not the rest?

If not, any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body class="notranslate">
    <p class="translate">Will be translated</p>
    <p>Will not be translated</p>
</body>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute `translate=""`, and specify on body. Then inside, specify what nodes to translate. For example:

```
<body translate="no">

    <p translate="yes">Will be translated</p>
    <p>Will not be translated</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Nitai. Your solution didn't work for me but you gave me a hint! I tried similar approach but with using class "notranslate" for the body and class "translate" for the elements I wanted to translate.

Comment: Yes it did! But I'm curious why your solution didn't. I checked on the w3school (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_translate.asp) and they suggested "Tip: Use class="notranslate" instead."

Comment: Might be some legacy code I have here that's outdated. I'll check this. I'm glad that you found a solution though.